# Can't resolve all parameters for HomeInnerComponent Angular 7

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I'm getting the below error in my console when trying to run my Angular application. Here is my html code if you need it https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xrbrjq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

> Error: Can't resolve all parameters for HomeInnerComponent: (?).

Please have a look below for my component details.

Home-inner.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {CategoriesService } from '../../Admin/categories/categories.service';
import {Categories } from '../../Admin/categories/categories';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home-inner',
  templateUrl: './home-inner.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home-inner.component.css']
})
export class HomeInnerComponent implements OnInit {
  leftCat:Categories;
  constructor(private leftCategoriesService: CategoriesService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    // For showing category list in the left side

    this.leftCategoriesService.getCategories()
    .subscribe((data: any) => {
      this.leftCat = data;
      //console.log(this.leftCat);
      // localStorage.removeItem('editEmpId');
    });

// Left side category list ends here

  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: your stackblitz link not working

Comment: check it now..I've updated it

Comment: component files are empty

Comment: I've posted the component file here only

Comment: Are you correctly adding `CategoriesService` to your module?